# How to update an item in Dynamodb of type String Set (SS)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a attribute of type String Set.
When I create the Item and assign an attribute of type SS everything works.
But when I try to update this attribute, the data type changes to a list ("L").

I try this:

```
qw = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
  TableName : "myTable",
  Key: {
    "id": somekey
  },
  UpdateExpression: "set ssvar= :arrp",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
     ":arrp": [ "test", "test2" ]
  }
};

qw.update (etc.)
```

This leads to a change in datatype in dynamodb and in stead of a string set I get a list:

```
"ssvar": {
            "L": [
                {
                    "S": "test"
                }, 
                {
                    "S": "test2"
                }
            ]
        }
```

I have tried all kinds of solutions like below but always my datatype gets changed.

```
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
     ":arrp": 
        "SS": [ "test", "test2" ]
  }
```

How can I update an attribute of type string set?

Comment: I have the same issue with Golang. A slice of strings gets converted to dynamodb List on dynamodbattribute.Marshal. How can I convert it to dynamodb Stringset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an artifact of using the DocumentClient - StringSet is not a JSON type.

The DocumentClient converts a StringSet to the Array native JavaScript type:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/dynamodb/converter.js#L61. Then the client serializes the native JavaScript Array as a DynamoDB List type: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/dynamodb/converter.js#L12.

If you want to use the StringSet type, you can use the low-level API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html

Answer (score 23):

As of September 2015, there is a [`createSet`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#createSet-property) function in the DocumentClient that you can use for this.

**UPDATE** - added example

I've modified your example code to use this function:

```
qw = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
  TableName : "myTable",
  Key: {
    "id": somekey
  },
  UpdateExpression: "set ssvar= :arrp",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
     ":arrp": qw.createSet([ "test", "test2" ])
  }
};

qw.update (etc.)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ekad Thanks, good tip. Updated the answer with an example :)

Comment: Just what I needed!

Comment: This is AWS SDK V2, any idea what the syntax looks like, for V3?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative simpler syntax

**Upsert Item and Add "A" to set**

```
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
await documentClient.update({
    TableName,
    Key: { hashKey, sortKey },
    AttributeUpdates: {
      'userIDs': {
        Action: 'ADD',
        Value: documentClient.createSet(['A' ])
      },
    },
  }).promise();
```

**Upsert Item and remove "A" from set**

```
await documentClient.update({
    TableName,
    Key: { hashKey, sortKey },
    AttributeUpdates: {
      'userIDs': {
        Action: 'DELTE',
        Value: documentClient.createSet(['A'])
      },
    },
  }).promise();
```

- [Update expression docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD)
- [documentClient.createSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#createSet-property)
- [documentClient.update](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#update-property)

Comment: Use of `AttributesUpdates` is not recommended for new applications.  See  documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.html)