# Add string to DynamoDB set of strings using ruby sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I try to add a string to a set of strings using ruby sdk.

```
dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(region: 'eu-central-1')
```

**I get the error:**

```
"Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: ADD, operand type: MAP, typeSet: ALLOWED_FOR_ADD_OPERAND"
```

In [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194794/how-to-update-an-item-in-dynamodb-of-type-string-set-ss/37220639) i find the use of `documentClient` but i can't find it in ruby documentation.
Can i add a string to the set using ruby?

**My code:**

```
require 'aws-sdk-dynamodb'
def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
    dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(region: 'eu-central-1')

    params = {
        table_name: 'Video',
        key: {
            "uuid": event['video_uuid']
        },
        update_expression: "ADD #like :uuid_user",
        expression_attribute_names: { "#like" => "like" },
        expression_attribute_values: {":uuid_user" => {"SS" => ["the string"]}  },
        return_values: 'UPDATED_NEW'
    }

    dynamodb.update_item(params)
end
```

**Attempt to initialize documentClient**

```
dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::DocumentClient.new(region: 'eu-central-1')
```

**Result:**

```
"errorMessage": "uninitialized constant Aws::DynamoDB::DocumentClient"**
```

Comment: Are you sure the `like` attribute is a set? It seems to think it's a map.

Comment: Yes it is a set of strings :( I rewrite the lambda function in nodejs and using `const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();` now it's working. I think that the ruby sdk is not complete